# Unable to sync database in my Django project

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python

My question is very similar to the questions that have been asked before by others, but those solutions provided have not solved my issue.

I am using Windows 7 OS,  python 2.7(Anaconda),I have installed mysql workbench. 
After creating a virtual environment, I created a testproject and also did

```
    pip install mysql-python
```

and made changes to the settings.py file

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'testdatabase', # have created a testdatabase in mysqlworkbench
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD':'syusuf125',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'3306',
}
```

however when I do
       `python manage.py migrate`
it says

```
traceback (most recent call last): File manage.py, line 10 in(module)execute_from_command_line(sys.argv) 
and ImproperlyConfigured: Error Loading MySQLdb module: no module named MySQLdb
```

manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "testproject.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv) #line 10
```

One thing I have noticed is, after a make changes to the database entries in settings.py file, that is when i get into trouble after that even

```
python manage.py runserver
```

command gives me errors but prior to that it works fine.

Comment: Hmm, it should work. Did you activate your virtualenv?

Comment: Shang Wang it is activated.